# How do computers set a register to a constant value?

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

**Warning 1:** I don't know anything about real-life practical CPU design.

**Warning 2:** I don't know the difference between terms like "CPU instruction", "CPU operation" and "CPU function". Maybe there is one, maybe there isn't, but I use these as if they are synonyms. Correct me if I am wrong.

**Background:** Imagine you have a 4-bit CPU with two registers. Now you need to load a constant value to register 1! There may be several ways to do that:

- Instruction like 0SXX, where 0 says that it is a "set register to X" kind of instruction, and S says to which side of register 1 the XX should be loaded.

  - Pros: easy manipulation of register 1. A constant value can be set using only two bytes of program memory.
  - Cons: consumes HALF of possible CPU instructions. For my 4-bit little device it's a tragedy, but perhaps that's not a big deal for >=8 bit computer.
- Pure arithmetical/bit-wise series of CPU functions (like AND, OR, NOT, XOR, RoR, RoL, INC, etc...)

  - Pros: no additional CPU implementation.
  - Cons: more instructions needed, slower loading of constant and of course, you need to think more before loading a constant in assembly.
- Something in between those? Like clearing registers, loading ??XX and then logical operations?
- Something else that I haven't thought of?

**Generally:**

- Is there a way that all normal, modern CPUs set registers to constant values?

  - If no, what is the most common way to do that?
- Did old, 4/8-bit computers have a different way to do that?

I think that anyone who has touched assembly would know the asnwer. I would very much appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearing a register is easy: `xor` it with itself is usually shorter to encode than a move-immediate to register instruction, which sets a register to a value that is contained in the instruction.  Out-of-order execution CPUs need to identify dependency chains so they can do all the independent things in parallel.  They always recognize `xor eax, eax` as independent of the previous value, so it breaks a dependency chain the same way `mov  eax, 0` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each processor architecture, x86, arm, mips, etc.  Has their own way of doing this.  You certainly cant get too much use out of a processor if you cant in some way operate on constants.

First and foremost not all processors use registers, some are stack based for example, you have the same problem though placing a constant on the stack in some way.

there are two basic approaches and both are found on most processors.  One is along the lines of what you implied, there are instructions that state this is a move immediate (immediate meaning the constant is encoded in the instruction itself) to register, the terminology will vary but the opcode, register number and immediate value are encoded in the instruction.  Depending on the cpu though you may not be able to load the entire register in one instruction, fixed length instruction sets for example, you cant fit an opcode, register number and a 32 bit value in 32 bits, so for example ARM and MIPS can only load a fraction of the register at once.  load a 0x00000078, then or in 0x00005600, then or in 0x00340000 then or in 0x12000000 or on another architecture load 0x00005678 and or in 0x12340000, resulting in 0x12345678.

The second approach is to place the constant in the program memory, often called .text, and then use an instruction that loads or moves data from memory to a register, using pc-relative addressing.  pc the program counter, basically a combination of the programmer and the assembler (the program that reads assembly language and makes machine code from it) has placed the instruction to load, and the data to load, and basically says, take the address of the instruction you are executing right now and add some number X and that produces an address of the constant I want to read and load into this register.  This second approach is available to most instruction sets and you now can load any size constant into a register you want depending on the rules of the instruction set, it doesnt take two or four or more instructions to piece together the constant you wanted in the case of a fixed instruction length instruction set, it doe cost you a memory cycle which may or may not be a performance hit.  If you think about the variable length instruction sets then constant is itself a separate read in the instruction flow so that tradeoff between architectures really isnt any different.

it doesnt matter how old or new the instruction set they have been historically as similar as they are different.  old to new instruction sets tend to use a few or more registers, have a program counter, have alu operations, add, and, or, not, xor, etc.  Have a way to read and write memory (load and store) and have the ability to use immediate values.  The older cisc processors and/or variable length instruction set processors offered more of these instructions, every alu operation having the ability to use a full width immediate, that kind of thing, and as you move into attempts to boost performance with risc, you sacrifice those features for faster pipelining, more instructions, but they move faster and smoother producing an overall faster execution (or other features).

The instruction set information is out there on the net for your consumption.  the pdp-11 or msp430 are a good first instruction set, I often recommend using simulators not hardware when learning assembly, avoid the x86 at first until you have one or two others under your belt.  msp430/pdp11, arm, mips, avr, etc.  After one or two the pdp8 is actually interesting and educational, of course you may want to then go dig up the 4004 or 8008 and work your way up to the 6502 and 6800 and 8080 and things like that.

Comment: Yes, reading value directly from ROM is a great idea! It saves so many slots for other instructions! Thank you very much! And thank You again for the analyzable (if there is a word like that) CPUs. I had this thought, looked at the x86 instruction set at wikipedia and was really discouraged. These don't look that terrifying at all!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the background to your question. If you're designing a 4 bit CPU you should perhaps read a little more than you seem to have done.

Most real-world CPUs use some bits of the opcode to describe the kind of operation (move, add, compare etc), and a few more bits to describe the addressing mode (constant, register, register indirect, memory indirect etc.). Not all CPUs offer all addressing modes for all opcodes (instruction sets with this property are called "orthogonal").

Trying to save "CPU implementation" (= reducing the number of opcodes) may be appropriate for rarely used "arcane" instructions (or for example for floating-point operations), but not for basic things like moving a constant value to a register.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer and new terms (opcodes, orthogonal)! Sorry, I know this question is probably silly, but I am just a self-learning, totally unexperienced teenager enthusiast guy, so books and articles on this topic are very difficult to decode for me (reading stuff all over again until you understand), that's why sometimes (like this time) I try to design things on my own, resulting these already, ages ago solved questions. Sorry.